# Preserve data integrity from external editing

Tags: c#, sql, database

I'm starting to do some research on a new application for which one of the requirements is to provide safe storage. Safe in a way to prevent that the data is being altered outside the application.

The records would be filled from EF into a SQL database to maintain ease of querying. We are examining several options but are having difficult to find any online content or guidelines (or perhaps standards).

1. We create a checksum of each row based on all fields. By reading the checksum back we can determine if the data was changed externally
2. Encrypt the data with public/private keys. The private key however would be embedded in the application and would have possibilities to be read back; so this would need some sort of security on the application itself by a hardware dongle or such.
3. Own file format instead of SQL server; but still no real security
4. Use blockchain; problem is that this application would most likely run embedded with no connection to the internet.

The background of the application is to gather measurement data from field sensors but we need to ensure that after testing / measuring no one has changed the data by accident (or on purpose).

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: How about setting the permissions on the tables so that it cannot be updated? e.g. only allow INSERT & SELECT.  You can do it so that your application does have permissions if needed, all others would not.      P.S. you might want to tag it with the type of database you intend to use.

Comment: Like anything else you want to secure it comes down to access and access permissions to where the data is stored (the RDBMs and server's it resides on). If you do not want external modifications made then do not grant access externally and control the credentials that do have access as well as access paths to the server(s) where the data is stored.

Comment: That is obviously our start; but yet our application will save data and I need to ensure that both the application and it's data are not being tempered by external sources. We will use a hardware dongle for the application but that leaves me with the data